# Force Embedded Jetty to disconnect at once

Tags: java, sockets, tcp, network-programming, jetty

I'm creating a small utility which receives a lot of HTTP requests. It is written in `java` and uses `embedded-jetty` to handle requests via `https`.

I have a load-testing tool for it, but when it is being run for some time it starts to throw exceptions:

```
java.net.BindException: Address already in use: connect
```

(note, this is on sender's side, not in my project)

As I understand this means no more free sockets were found in system when another `connect` was called. Throughput is about `1000` requests per second, and failures start to appear somewhere after `20000` to `50000` requests.

However when I use the same load testing tool with another program (a kind of simple consumer, written in `scala` using `netty` by some colleague - it simply receives all requests and returns empty `ok` response) - there is no so problem with sockets (though typical speed is `1.5-2` times slower).

I wonder if this could be fixed by telling Jetty somehow to close connections immediately after response was sent. Anyway each new request is sent via new connection. I tried to play with [Connector#setIdleTimeout](http://download.eclipse.org/jetty/9.2.10.v20150310/apidocs/org/eclipse/jetty/server/AbstractConnector.html#setIdleTimeout(long)) - it seems to be 30000 by default but have not succeeded.

What can I do to fix this - or at least to research the matter deeper to find its cause (if I am wrong in my suggestions)?

**UPD** Thanks for suggestions, I think I am not allowed to post the source, but I get the idea that I should study client's code (this will make me busy for some time since it is written in scala).

Comment: What happens after data is exchanged b/w server and client? You can find when the connection usage is done , isn't? Simply drop the connection. `socket.close`? The error at high load is basically, there are no more free ephemeral ports available for use.

Comment: "this is on sender's side"  Does that mean the load-testing tool is reporting that?  If so, it's not your server but your tool that is unable to `bind()` to a local port because they're all in-use.  Fix it by always binding to the same local port number with `SO_REUSEADDR`.  Note that `bind()` is called implicitly by `connect()` (with port #0) if the socket has not already been bound.  Just bind in explicitly first.

Comment: this kind of jetty behavior is usually the result of a bad client behavior.  i would wager that the http connection persistence isn't being handled properly on the client side.  post the request headers and response headers of one of the transactions.

Comment: Post your client load testing code.  The problem is likely in that code.

Answer (score 0):

I found that really there was a problem with client - it sends requests with `Connection: Keep-Alive` in header, though creates new `HttpURLConnection` for each request and calls `disconnect()` method after it.

To solve this trouble on the server-side it was sufficient to send `Connection: close` in response header, since I have no allowance to change testing utility.